# Change text color to white on any non-white background

Tags: css, mix-blend-mode

Changing the text color to white when the background color is black works great using `mix-blend-mode: difference`. Move the mouse to the text to see the effect:

```js
const blackBox = document.querySelector(".black-box");
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  blackBox.style.left = `${event.pageX - 50}px`;
  blackBox.style.top = `${event.pageY - 50}px`;
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: white;
}
h1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  color: white;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

.black-box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
</div>
<div class="black-box"></div>
```

This understandably doesn't result in white text if the background is anything other than black:

```js
const box = document.querySelector(".box");
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  box.style.left = `${event.pageX - 50}px`;
  box.style.top = `${event.pageY - 50}px`;
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: white;
}
h1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  color: white;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-image: url("https://placekitten.com/100/100")
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
</div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Is there any way to make it so the text changes color from black to white as soon as the background differs from white?

Comment: in this particular case or a generic solution? I doubt mix-blend-mode will help here

Comment: A generic solution would be optimal. Alright, thank you for your insight! I have an image that can change that the user can move with the mouse over text, and the text should go from black to white like the first code snippet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an idea that rely on background coloration and not `mix-blend-mode`. The trick is to have a gradient with the same dimension as the image that you move the same way to simulate the blend mode:

```js
const box = document.querySelector(".box");
const h1 = document.querySelector("h1");
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  box.style.left = `${event.pageX - 50}px`;
  box.style.top = `${event.pageY - 50}px`;
  
  h1.style.backgroundPosition = `${event.pageX - 50}px ${event.pageY - 50}px`;
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: white;
}
h1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  color: white;
  background: 
    /*gradient                   position   /    size  */
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) -100px -100px/100px 100px fixed no-repeat,
    #000;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-image: url("https://placekitten.com/100/100")
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
</div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

I have considered `background-attachment:fixed` to place the gradient relatively to the viewport since your element is `position:absolute` with no ancestor positioned so it's also positioned relatively to the viewport.