# Change overlapping pixels in css

Tags: html, css

On some websites, the cursor is some shape, which is easy enough to do, make a div with some css that follows the mouse.

But on some other sites, I see that when the cursor moves, it filters on a pixel by pixel basis depending on what element it is hovering over, eg:
[image]

the circle is the cursor. when it's over the red square, those overlapping pixels are cyan, the others are red, the rest of the circle is the original white.

How can this be accomplished in css/js/html

Any help appreciated?

Comment: Have a look at [mix-blend-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode). It's still very new, but it is supported in chrome, firefox, and opera

Comment: thanks, make it an answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49793312/8620333

Comment: more ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54674595/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/q/55424824/8620333 /

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [mix-blend-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode). It's still very new, but it is supported in chrome, firefox, and opera

```js
let img = $("#cursor");

$(document).on('mousemove', function(e){
    img.css({
       left:  e.pageX,
       top:   e.pageY
    });
});
```

```css
#cursor {
  position: absolute;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="https://picsum.photos/200">

<img src="https://picsum.photos/32" id="cursor">
```